# CSS horizontal gaps between html sections

Tags: css, html

Hello I know this question is probably quite basic but I can't seem to find the solution, I am trying to get rid of the white bars/gaps between elements on the page. here is my code and output thanks.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cv1Eu.png  html
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5R0W.png  css
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OAaw.png output

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea to add `margin: 0` and `padding: 0` to the sections and paragraphs in order to remove the "gaps" however I think there is a syntax error in your CSS.

It looks like you're trying to target all of the section `<p>` tags with the following CSS:

```
.Section1, .Section2, .Section3 p{
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

However it should be as follows:

```
.Section1 p, .Section2 p, .Section3 p{
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

If you make this change the gaps will disappear.

Comment: @Ryan No probs :)